# How to show/hide list columns using checkboxes

Tags: list-view, view

I have a list with 30 columns. My "Allitems" view will generate a long horizontal scrolling and not all users need to see all columns on the same page. Now, I know users can create their own personal views etc.. but I have executive users who are not very familiar with SharePoint and don't want to deal with views.

I'd like to:

1. Add a webpart on top of that list.
2. Fill that webpart with checkboxes, one checkbox per each column on my list.
3. Add an "Update View" button on the webpart so that when I click on it, only the selected columns will display on the page.

Is that even possible? Perhaps using CSS to display or hide the columns? some JS to create the checkboxes? Should I just forget about it?

[image: Here's how I think it would look:]

Answer (score 0):

Let us say you want one group to view first 15 columns and one group to view last 30 columns. 
Create a page and add two List View webparts. 
1st web part: Select the list and give the first 15 columns to that view.
Under Edit Web part > Advanced > Target Audience select the group one

2nd web part: Select the list and give the last 15 columns to that view.
Under Edit Web part > Advanced > Target Audience select the group two

Comment: Hi Jackie, thank you for replying to this question. What I'm actually looking for, is a way to let users pick the columns they want to see and hide the rest. Some columns are important for some users but not for others. Experienced SharePoint users can easily create views that fit their needs, but people who aren't familiar with SharePoint could find this tool very useful.

Comment: Did you ever get it sorted @RickyGzz?